# Creating a Custom Table View and Getting the error "Type SecondViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableviewDataSource'

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview

I'm coding in Swift for an app and tried following a tutorial on YouTube for writing up a custom view controller.

Video tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVJiprvRLoo

I've come with a few errors, mainly being that my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function doesn't want to work properly, and the tutorial does it differently to the standard that is the new Xcode 8 I believe.

Second and most pain of an error is

> Type SecondViewController does not conform to protocol 'UITableviewDataSource'

Any help?
Edit: I have it coming up with no errors with the code below, but when i select the page from my view controller the app crashes.

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet  var tableView: UITableView!

    var names = ["Day1","Day2","Day3","Day4","Day5","Day6","Day7" ]

    var Description = ["Arrive Mt Victoria, Blue Mountains","Mt Piddington - Fairy Bower and Cox's cave via Rhododendron Gardens to Black Heath","Popes Glen - Horseshoe Falls - Govett’s Leaps to Braeside Creek Circuit","Scenic Railway - Federal Pass to Ruined Castle","Three Sisters, Giant Stairway, Dardanelles’ Pass, Leura","Three Sisters, Giant Stairway, Dardanelles’ Pass, Leura","Last Day" ]

    var images = [UIImage(named:"Day1"), UIImage(named:"Day2"), UIImage(named:"Day3"), UIImage(named:"Day4"), UIImage(named:"Day5"), UIImage(named:"Day6"), UIImage(named:"Day7")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
             // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return names.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"cell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.photo.image = images[indexPath.row]
        cell.Name.text = names[indexPath.row]
        cell.Description.text = Description[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the signature of both the methods cellForRowAt IndexPath and numberOfRowsInSection. In swift 3.0 these signatures are changed.

Comment: So now the error is gone but your app is crashing? Can you post a log of the crash